# How can I force form elements to render the same across browsers?

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

Here is an image of how my contact form looks in all the different browsers:

[image]

I've tried editing some of the CSS but I'm looking for complete control over these elements, but I also don't want to lose flexibility (I am also using jQuery).

Is there a way to override the browsers rendering methods for these text areas, or am I stuck with the default styling?

Comment: See [Remove default browser styles on form elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3616518/remove-default-browser-styles-on-form-elements). The accepted answer says it perfectly. There are ways to do it, but it relies on javascript, is never guaranteed, and honestly: You don't need it. You might think you do, but you don't. Not to shoot you down, but there's no specification on how browsers style form controls with CSS. You have to take what you can get.

Comment: I used the normalized.css method to some degree. It is explained below. thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [normalize.css](https://github.com/necolas/normalize.css/blob/master/normalize.css) (Form elements begin on 293). normalize.css makes browsers render all elements consistently and in line with modern standards. It's not a quick fix but at least it will give your elements some consistency for which to work on. If you use this, make sure you load it before your other styles otherwise the normalize.css styles will override your main stylesheet.

Comment: I didnt have to load the entire normalize css. I simply copied 5 to 6 of the lines into the current css I was using and it works across all browsers perfectly. I would make a jpeg of all of them combined again but I dont need to! this is what it looks like across all platforms [with minor stying differences] http://imgur.com/714bs

Answer (score 1):

Try using [normalize.css](http://necolas.github.com/normalize.css/). It provides a cross-browser compatibility solution for most CSS elements.